# Solidity IDEs with background compilation for OSX

Tags: solidity, remix, mac-osx

Are there yet any Solidity IDEs or editors that

- Run OSX
- Allow editing a folder of local Solidity source code files with includes or library support
- Highlight compiler error as you type them

Please correct me if I am wrong: the browser based IDE works for a simple contract, but breaks down when you need to include multiple contracts that you keep in a version control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find a list of the all available IDE in the official doc :

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#available-solidity-integrations

in my experience i think the online Ethereum Studio(based on cloude9 IDE) is quite interesting besides the usage of ATOM and ethereum/solidity plugin.

Answer (score 4):

There is a private build of the https://github.com/webdaford/smart-contract-tools projects of a solidity editor for eclipse.

http://opensource.urszeidler.de/SolidityEditor-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip (pre 0.4.0 solidity) and
http://opensource.urszeidler.de/SolidityEditor-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip

It has

- syntax highlighting
- context sensitive code completion
- syntax check
- code templates

see [SolidityEditor](https://github.com/UrsZeidler/uml2solidity/wiki/SolidityEditor)

You could use the https://github.com/UrsZeidler/uml2solidity/wiki/SolidityBuilder to compile the contract code or simply call solc as configured external tool.

With https://github.com/adridadou/eth-contract-api you can write the contract test in java as junit tests, on the standalone chain the tests runs fast.